# Can I force a subclass to declare a constant?

Tags: c#

I want to force subclasses to define a constant value.

Like

```
const string SomeConstantEverySubclassMustDefine = "abc";
```

I need that because I need to have it tied to the Type, rather than to the instance and you can't override static Methods/Properties iirc.

I'd really like to have a compile-time check for those constants.

Let me explain in more detail:

Some classes in our Domain-Model are special, you can take certain actions for them, depending on the type. Thus the logic is tied to the type. The action to be taken requires a string tied to the type. I sure could create an instance everytime as a workaround and declare an abstract property, but that's not what I want. I want to enforce the declaration of the string at compile-time, just to be sure.

Comment: No, you can't.  Out of curiosity, how would you intend to get the value for the constants without a contract (like an interface) to allow you to get the value in a generic fashion?

Comment: MyAbstractBaseObject.TheDefinedConstant

where MyAbstractBaseObject returns the constant declared in the concrete type.

Comment: Sorry, that was bullshit.

It's quite difficult. I currently use reflection to obtain the value. I'd just really like to make sure it is there and I need it on the type rather than the instance, since it's the same value for each instance. Much like static but with inheritance.

Comment: @Falcon: *Which* concrete type though?

Comment: Maybe there's a chance with ATTRIBUTES?

Comment: @Falcon: I just thought of a sort of weird way you could consider to accomplish something *like* this. Take a look at my updated answer and see if comes anywhere close to achieving what you want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, you can't. I would suggest you make your base class abstract, with an abstract property which you can fetch when you want. Each child class can then implement the property just by returning a constant if it wants. The downside is that you can't use this within static methods in the base class - but those aren't associated with the child classes anyway.

(It also *allows* child classes to customise the property per instance as well, if necessary... but that's rarely an actual problem.)

If this doesn't do enough for you, you might want to consider a parallel type hierarchy. Basically polymorphism simply doesn't happen in a type-specific way in .NET; only in an instance-specific way.

If you *still* want to do this and fetch it with reflection, I suggest you just write unit tests to ensure that the relevant constants are defined. When you get beyond what the type system can describe, that's often the best you can do.

Comment: Maybe there's a chance with attributes?

Comment: +1 for validation via unit tests.  Runtime checks are almost as good as compile-time checks as long as you make sure to exercise them regularly.

Comment: @Falcon, I think attributes are a better way to associate the data, but you still won't get compile-time validation that the attributes are actually present.  As Jon mentioned, though, you can validate this at runtime and make sure you have tests that exercise this check for the necessary types.

Comment: I do have a use case for this, so I came here. All the derived class inherits "item" have a "label name" which is a const for each class. And I need to access it from both instance.label and static ClassType.label. The virtual property is not enough for me.

Comment: @ZonyZhao: My answer hasn't changed since 2010. What you're looking for still isn't possible as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 10):

Make an `abstract property` with only a `get`.  That's what I think you could do to enforce a class has a value.  Then you can just return a constant in the property.

##### Example:

Base class:

```
public abstract string MyConst { get; }
```

Derived class:

```
public override string MyConst {
    get { return "constant"; }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me using an interface.

Comment: It works, except for the case commented in the accepted answer: "you can't use this within static methods". So you also cannot access the value of that string directly from the class, you need an instanced object.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, but didn't know if it was possible in C#. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I made mine work. I used Attribute as others have suggested.

```
public class ObjectAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int ObjectSize { get; set; }
    public ObjectAttribute(int objectSize)
    {
        this.ObjectSize = objectSize;
    }
}
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    public static int GetObjectSize<T>() where T : IPacket
    {
        ObjectAttribute[] attributes = (ObjectAttribute[])typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ObjectAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].ObjectSize : 0;
    }
}
[ObjectAttribute(15)]
public class AObject : BaseObject
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
[ObjectAttribute(25)]
public class BObject : BaseObject
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

If you would like instance access to the attribute just add it to the base abstract class.

```
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    public static int GetObjectSize<T>() where T : IPacket
    {
        ObjectAttribute[] attributes = (ObjectAttribute[])typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ObjectAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].ObjectSize : 0;
    }

    public int ObjectSize 
    {
        get
        {
            ObjectAttribute[] attributes = (ObjectAttribute[])GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ObjectAttribute), false);
            return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].ObjectSize : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage of the constants

```
int constantValueA = AObject.GetObjectSize<AObject>();
int constantValueB = BObject.GetObjectSize<BObject>();
AObject aInstance = new AObject();
int instanceValueA = aInstance.ObjectSize;
```

Comment: This is a good solution to have constant values available statically and per-instance where they are different between derived classes of the same base class. I've used this solution myself (upvote), but it doesn't allow compile-time enforcement like the OP required.

Comment: This doesn't force anything...  You're still dependent on the subclass inheritor to know they need to add a custom attribute to the class.

Answer (score 6):

### New idea

Here's a sort of weird idea: instead of using inheritance directly, you create a separate class to provide a constant value for every type deriving from some type `T`. The constructor for *this* type uses reflection to verify that every derived type has indeed been supplied a value.

```
public abstract class Constant<T, TConstant>
{
    private Dictionary<Type, TConstant> _constants;
    
    protected Constant()
    {
        _constants = new Dictionary<Type, TConstant>();
        
        // Here any class deriving from Constant<T, TConstant>
        // should put a value in the dictionary for every type
        // deriving from T, using the DefineConstant method below.
        DefineConstants();
        
        EnsureConstantsDefinedForAllTypes();
    }
    
    protected abstract void DefineConstants();

    protected void DefineConstant<U>(TConstant constant) where U : T
    {
        _constants[typeof(U)] = constant;
    }
    
    private void EnsureConstantsDefinedForAllTypes()
    {
        Type baseType = typeof(T);
        
        // Here we discover all types deriving from T
        // and verify that each has a key present in the
        // dictionary.
        var appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        var assemblies = appDomain.GetAssemblies();
        var types = assemblies
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .Where(t => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t));
        
        foreach (Type t in types)
        {
            if (!_constants.ContainsKey(t))
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    string.Format("No constant defined for type '{0}'.", t)
                );
            }
        }
    }
    
    public TConstant GetValue<U>() where U : T
    {
        return _constants[typeof(U)];
    }
}
```

Basic example:

```
public class BaseType
{
    public static Constant<BaseType, string> Description { get; private set; }
    
    static BaseType()
    {
        Description = new BaseTypeDescription();
    }
}

public class DerivedType : BaseType
{ }

internal sealed class BaseTypeDescription : Constant<BaseType, string>
{
    public BaseTypeDescription() : base()
    { }
    
    protected override DefineConstants()
    {
        DefineConstant<BaseType>("A base type");
        DefineConstant<DerivedType>("A derived type");
    }
}
```

Now I have code that allows me to do this:

```
var description = BaseType.Description;

// returns "A base type"
string baseTypeDescription = description.GetValue<BaseType>();

// returns "A derived type"
string derivedTypeDescription = description.GetValue<DerivedType>();
```

---

### Original answer

You may not like it, but the closest way to accomplish this is by declaring an abstract read-only (no `set`) property.

If you've got an instance of your subclass, then this can work just as well as a constant, even though it is technically instance-level (it will just be the same for all instances of the given class).

Consider, for instance, `IList.IsReadOnly`. In most cases this is actually a property that tells you about the underlying class implementation, as opposed to any state specific to a particular instance. (It may be an interface member as opposed to an abstract class member, but it's the same idea.)

If you are trying to access it statically, well... then you're out of luck. But in this case I fail to see how you'd obtain the value without using reflection anyway. Maybe that's your intention; I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a static method in the base class called, for instance "Register", that is passed a Type and a constant value, with the intention being that it is called by the class constructors of the subtypes. Then, add a check in all of your base class constructors that the object being constructed is of a registered type.

```
abstract class Base
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, string> _registry = new Dictionary<Type, string>();

    protected static void Register(Type t, string constVal)
    {
        _registry.Add(t, constVal);
    }

    protected Base()
    {
        if(!_registry.ContainsKey(this.GetType()))
        throw new NotSupportedException("Type must have a registered constant");
    }

    public string TypeConstant
    {
        get
        {
            return _registry[this.GetType()];
        }
    }
}

class GoodSubtype : Base
{
    static GoodSubtype()
    {
        Base.Register(typeof(GoodSubtype), "Good");
    }

    public GoodSubtype()
        : base()
    {
    }
}

class Badsubtype : Base
{
    public Badsubtype()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

And then elsewhere, you can construct GoodSubtype instances, but trying to construct a Badsubtype gets an exception. I think a runtime error at construction is the soonest you can get an error with this type of scheme.

(You'd want to use ConcurrentDictionary for your registry if threading is involved)

Comment: Looks like you and I had similar ideas. However, this seems (to me) to be rather lacking as a solution since you are still making `TypeConstant` an instance member. If you can't access the value statically, there's really no point going through all this trouble: the `TypeConstant` property could just as easily be a regular virtual property, overridden by every type deriving from `Base` (as other answers have suggested) with a constant value.

Comment: But the registry is available to static methods of the base class.

Comment: And you're also ensuring the value stays the same across instances, which you don't get with the virtual property (i.e. you enforce the "const"-ness)

Answer (score 1):

There's one other method that hasn't been covered and it uses the `new` modifier to hide `consts` values in the base class. In a way, it's similar to Nap's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9509559/197591), but doesn't allow per-instance access and therefore doesn't allow for polymorphic access within the base class. This solution is only useful if you want to have constant value defined but wish to have the option of changing it to different values in different subclasses.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BaseClass.MyConst = {0}, ClassA.MyConst = {1}, ClassB.MyConst = {2}", BaseClass.MyConst, ClassA.MyConst, ClassB.MyConst);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

class BaseClass
{
    public const int MyConst = 1;
}

class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    public new const int MyConst = 2;
}

class ClassB : BaseClass
{
}
```